# Very strange error trying to translate C# code into a VB.NET WPF application

Tags: wpf, vb.net, nevron

This is the original Nevron example code:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        App app = new App();
        NModule[] modules = new NModule[] { 
              // TODO: Create modules here
        };
        NNOVApplicationInstaller.Install(modules);
        app.Run(new MainWindow());
    }
}
```

And this is my rough approximation:

Public NotInheritable Class Program

```
Private Sub New()
End Sub

<STAThread> _
Shared Sub Main()

    Dim app As Application = New Application()
    Dim modules As NModule() = New NModule() {}
    NNOVApplicationInstaller.Install(modules)
    app.Run(New MainWindow)

End Sub
```

End Class

Yet when I try and compile, I get this brain frazzling error:

```
'Sub Main' is declared more than once in 'DataMonitor.Visuals': DataMonitor.Visuals.Program.Main(), DataMonitor.Visuals.Application.Main()  DataMonitor.Visuals
```

Yet There is no `Main` anywhere else in the entire project, only in my class.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think its that Sub New() is the equivalent to Sub Main() in vb... ie its the sub that is run when the class is used... someone will no doubt explain it more technically. Try removing the Sub New()...

Comment: Nope. Still the same. The `Sub New` just prevents instantiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the Application Framework is enabled for VB.NET projects.  That creates the `Main` method for you in code that you can't access.  If you want to write your own `Main` method then you have to disable the Application Framework in the project properties.

Note that, with the Application Framework enabled, you're supposed to handle the `Startup` event of the application, which you can access from the project properties also.  That event is raised from the auto-generated `Main` method.

Comment: Great, thanks. Dunno why they can't just have different language files and all the other bloody stuff the same.

Comment: The point of VB is to be easier for beginners.  Features like the Application Framework are part of that.

Comment: Jeez, @jmcilhinney, you could have fooled me. I used to be a VB6 expert, my first job. Now that was easy. Now nothing flows from my fingers like C#.

Comment: A fine point on: "Application Framework is enabled"... "creates the Main method".  Disabling this removes Application.xaml from the build by modifying the .vbproj file, and therefore msbuild does not generate the Application.g.vb file, which would have included Sub Main (and an Application.InitializeComponent instance method, which sets up the stuff you specify in Application.xaml).